# Getting class parameter out of an object

Tags: php, dom

I have this peace of code. This is PHP, not javascript.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
```

So in $imgs variable sits object with tag img. But some of my img tags have classes, and some no. What I want to do now is to check which $imgs has class. So how can I do that ?

Comment: has class? what do you mean? maybe  if every ``img`` has a css class attached to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works fine and catches all `img`'s who have a class set:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    if($img->getAttribute('class')){
          // has class
    } else {
         // no class
    }
}
```